# Getting "docker": executable file not found in $PATH using marathon

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon

I'm trying to launch an app on marathon, here's it's json:

```
{
    "id": "jackex",
    "container": {
        "docker": {
            "image": "ubuntu:14.04"
        },
        "type": "DOCKER",
        "volumes": []
    },
    "cmd": "while sleep 10; do date -u +%T; done",
    "cpus": 0.2,
    "mem": 200,
    "instances": 1
}
```

But I'm getting the following error on the tasks log:

> "docker": executable file not found in $PATH

Does anyone knows what's the problem?

Comment: probably your slaves don't have Docker installed? Try logging in onto your slave and see what `docker` command outputs. Mesos does not come with Docker preinstalled

Comment: I fixed it, the slave already had docker installed, I just needed to pass the flag --docker with the right docker executable instead of the default one.

Comment: @luis.alves I have only one docker installed, so to which executable do I need to pass the `--docker` flag , I am also facing the same issue